# do the queries for values analyzed with hierarchical path work correctly in Kibana and ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a field in my docs which are stored in ElasticSearch which analyzed with hierarchical_path tokenizer / analyzer.

It gets analysed correctly :

`a/b/c` is broken down into `a`, `a/b`, `a/b/c` terms

and

`a/b/d` into `a`, `a/b`, `a/b/d` (as expected).

But when I use Kibana to query on this field, e.g. for `a/b/c` - I am also getting values for `a/b/d`.

Am I doing something wrong or Kibana doesn't support this type of queries?

Regards, Roman

Comment: From my experience Kibana works best with a relatively flat json structure. I converted all the nested json structs to flat ones and got the results I wanted.

Comment: I have flat docs already, the hierarchy is in value of the field which is a file_name. So I want to be able to find for all the docs which have "a/b/c" in the file name (including files which are below a/b/c level) but not with "a/b/d" in the name

Answer (score 1):

Kibana makes use of query_string queries, so the query you enter is analyzed as well. This results in a query for the following terms:

a, a/b, a/b/c so it will find the a/b/d which is analysed into a, a/b, a/b/d as well.

You could use a term filter instead of a query to overcome this.

Comment: thanks a lot Jettro, this sounds like a good suggestion but I am not sure I am following. This field (in my case it is a path to a dir) is used to query a list of files which are further restricted with extra filters (by timestamp for example). How would you use a filter in this scenario to restrict on un-wanted files?

Comment: alternatively, if the "search" query gets analyzed with the same analyzer as for indexing, is it possible to add a custom search_analyser which will only pick up the longest term? e.g. if string_query is analyzed by the search_analyser associated with the field in the mapping and broken down into "a", "a/b", "a/b/c" - is i s possible to create a custom search_analyser which will only use "a/b/c" term? maybe it is possible to add a filter to search_analyser ot get rid of the shorter terms and keep the longest only?

Comment: Can you provide the query that you are performing? Use the "i" on top of the panel. Also the mapping would be nice.