# how to keep *only* longest term produced by PathHierarchy tokenizer in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to use PathHierarchy tokenizer during indexing stage. (so I could generate terms like "a", "a/b", "a/b/c".

But during search stage I would like to only keep the longest term ("a/b/c"). I need this because Kibana uses query_string type of queries so the query_string itself is analyzesed.

(question regarding Kibana queries is here:
[do the queries for values analyzed with hierarchical path work correctly in Kibana and ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833983/do-the-queries-for-values-analyzed-with-hierarchical-path-work-correctly-in-kiba))

is it possible to create a custom analyzer which will use path_hierarchy tokenizer and then will apply a filter which will only keep the longest term?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different analyser for indexing and searching. Maybe this mapping can help you:

```
PUT /myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "mytype":{
      "properties": {
        "path": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": " path_hierarchy",
          "search_analyzer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: oh, of course, this makes perfect sense. you are absolutely right! thank you Jettro

Comment: @user3482427 this appears to have met your need and be the correct answer to your question. Can you please accept it as such to verify it solved your problem?